# How can I add my javascript to my php for each loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

How can I add the below script to my php for each loop? so that who_likes?id passes the correct parameter?

any help, or example codes would be massively appreciated!

I have included the script that works and the php that works, im just not sure how I am going to go about combining the two files.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".button").hover(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "who_likes.php?id='$id'",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
}, function () {
    $("#div1").html("");
});


});
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
 #div1 {
background:#666;
color:#fff;
width:300px;
position:absolute;
}
 </style>

</head>

<body>
<a href="none.html" class="button">none</a>
<button>Button!</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

and then this file

```
<?php
include './authenticate.php';
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<?php
$user_type = $_SESSION["user"]["user_level"];
$user_id   = $_SESSION["user"]["user_id"]; //displays 1008
?>

<h1>Public TipsM/h1>
<?php include 'connection.php';

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
         die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

$liker_id = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('connection here');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM public_tips ORDER by date"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
{ $rows[] = $row; }

foreach($rows as $row) 
{ 
$date = $row['date'];
$date = date("d/m/y", strtotime($date));
$id = $row['id'];
$booky = $row['booky'];
$sp = $row['sp'];
$placed = $row['placed'];
// if ($sp === 'yes') {$start = ' SP';

$query2 = "select count(distinct liker_id) as counted from likes where id = $id";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()) { 
//$likes = $row2['count(liker_id)'];
$likes = $row2['counted'];
}

echo  
'<div style="float:left; width:700px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:150px; padding:10px; border: solid 1px grey;">
  <h5>
        ('.$date.") " .
         $row['time'] . " " . 
         $row['course'] . " - " . 
         $row['horse'] . " " . 
         $row['odds1'] . "/" . $row['odds2'] . $row['sp'] . "-" . $row['place'] .
         '</h4><br>'. 
         $row['description'] . '<br/>' . $likes . ' likes - 
         <a href="process_likes.php?table_id='.$table_id.'&id='.$id.'&liker_id='.$liker_id.'" />LIKE</a> | 

//
//I need to add script below here so that each who_likes.php has the right parameter??           
//

         <a href="who_likes.php?id='.$id.'"  class="button" target="_blank">who likes?</a> // script here???



         <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="'.$booky.'"><br/><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Best Odds"></FORM><br/><span style="font-size:10px">Added ' . 

         $row['date_added'] . ' at ' . $row['time_added'] . ' by ' . $row['username'].  '</span></div>' ;

         $horse = $row['horse'];
         $date = $row['date']; 

        echo '</div><div style="clear:both"/>';

}
$result->close(); 
$result2->close();
$mysqli->close(); 

?>

</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your link already has the right id in it. `<a href="who_likes.php?id='.$id.'"  class="button" target="_blank">who likes?</a>` Can't your script use that?

Comment: Have you heard about javascript templates? You return JSON from PHP and nest it with JS template.

Comment: Moob - how can I include the script into my foreach loop? do I have to echo the script each time I return a new row?

Comment: pbibergal - no I haven't, do you have any GOOD references?

Comment: @EdWright No, you should have just one script that works for all. It can use the url provided in the href. What's not clear is whether the 'who likes' data that is returned will be shown in a single universal element or separate elements for each instance.

Comment: The who likes data will eventually be a php file that uses the parameter in an sql select.  Eg. Select data where id = $id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` param is already in the `a href`. Just use that:

```
$(".wholikesbutton").hover(function () {
    var dataSource = $(this).attr("href");
    var dataDisplay = $(this).siblings(".wholikesdata");
    dataDisplay.text("fetching data from "+dataSource+"...");
    $.ajax({
        url: dataSource,
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function (html) {
        dataDisplay.html(html);
    })
    .fail(function (html) {
        dataDisplay.html("something went wrong (not suprisingly as the data source url doenst exist in this example)");
    });
}, function () {
    //seems a bit silly to actually remove the data when you could just hide it but if that's what you want...
    var dataDisplay = $(this).siblings(".wholikesdata");
    dataDisplay.text("");
});
```

I've mocked up [an example to show you the principles](http://jsfiddle.net/D5Skb/2/). FWIW I wouldn't be fetching this data every time the user hovers unless the data it likely to change incredibly often.

Comment: Ok fair point, but surely my data would change on every different hover, as I would be passing a different parameter on each row I return?

Comment: Yes, your data is different but as you'll see in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5Skb/3/) each is in its own instance.

Answer (score 0):

As Moob already said, it looks like you already have the correct URL in your links. To access it you could do something like this:

```js
$(".button").hover(function (evt) {
    var url = $(evt.target).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
}, function () {
    $("#div1").html("");
});
```